# How to return an XML element value from a Descendant when passing in another element value from that Descendant

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am new to working with LINQ to XML, but I can see how it could be helpful to my current problem. I want a method that you pass in an XML Document and an Element value, the method would then return a different Element Value from the same Descendant. For example if I provided a "StationName" I would like to know what "ScannerType" belongs to that "StationName"

Here is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<stations>
  <station>
    <stationName>CH3CTRM1</stationName>
    <scannerType>GE LightSpeed VCT</scannerType>
    <scannerID>COL02</scannerID>
    <siteName>CUMC</siteName>
    <inspDose>180</inspDose>
    <expDose>100</expDose>
    <kernel>STANDARD</kernel>
  </station>
  <station>
    <stationName>CTAWP75515</stationName>
    <scannerType>SIEMENS Force</scannerType>
    <scannerID>UIA07</scannerID>
    <siteName>Iowa</siteName>
    <inspDose>careDose</inspDose>
    <expDose>careDose</expDose>
    <kernel>Qr40 5</kernel>
  </station>
  <station>
    <stationName>JHEB_CT06N_JHOC2</stationName>
    <scannerType>SIEMENS Force</scannerType>
    <scannerID>JHU04</scannerID>
    <siteName>JHU</siteName>
    <inspDose>careDose</inspDose>
    <expDose>careDose</expDose>
    <kernel>Qr40 5</kernel>
  </station>
</stations>
```

Here are the methods that are currently in question

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ManualPhantomProcessor.XMLParser
{
    class SearchXML
    {
        public string filename = "SiteData.xml";
        public string currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

        public XDocument LoadXML()
        {
            string siteDataFilePath = Path.Combine(currentDirectory, filename);
            XDocument siteData = XDocument.Load(siteDataFilePath);
            return siteData;

        }

        public IEnumerable<string> GetScannerModel(XDocument xmlDocument, string stationName)
        {
            var query = xmlDocument.Descendants("station")
                .Where(s => s.Element("stationName").Value == stationName)
                .Select(s => s.Element("scannerType").Value)
                .Distinct();

            return query;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Programs.cs file

```
using ManualPhantomProcessor.XMLParser;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ManualPhantomProcessor
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SearchXML searchXML = new SearchXML();

            XDocument siteData = searchXML.LoadXML();

            IEnumerable<string> data = searchXML.GetScannerModel(siteData, "CH3CTRM1");

            Console.WriteLine(data);
        }
    }
}
```

I should be a simple console application, but it seem like no matter what I try I keep getting a null value when I expect the scannerType value from the XML document that corresponds with the station name "CH3CTRM1"

the application doesn't crash but in my console I get the following:
`` System.Linq.Enumerable+DistinctIterator`1[System.String] ``

Could explain what I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is good, the problem is here `Console.WriteLine(data);` the `WriteLine` take `string` like a parameter not a list of `string`. to display the station names use a loop, like the following code :

```
foreach(string stationName in data)
{
   Console.WriteLine(stationName);
}
```

The documentation of [WriteLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netframework-4.8)

i hope that will help you fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is the string form of the `IEnumerable<string>` returned by `GetScannerModel()`.

There are two possibilities:

- Only one scanner model is expected to be found (because a station name is expected
  to be unique).
- Any number of scanner models can be found.

In the first case, change `GetScannerModel()` to return a `string` and have it do soemthing like `return query.FirstOrDefault();` (or `.First()` if you want an exception if no match was found). Your client program then remains unchanged.

In the second case, @Sajid's answer applies - you need to enumerate the `IEnumerable` in some way, for example through `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<Station> stations = doc.Descendants("station").Select(x => new Station
            {
                stationName = (string)x.Element("stationName"),
                scannerType = (string)x.Element("scannerType"),
                scannerID = (string)x.Element("scannerID"),
                siteName = (string)x.Element("siteName"),
                inspDose = (string)x.Element("inspDose"),
                expDose = (string)x.Element("expDose"),
                kernel = (string)x.Element("kernel")
            }).ToList();

            Dictionary<string, Station> dict = stations
                .GroupBy(x => x.stationName, y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

        }
    }
    public class Station
    {
        public string stationName {get;set;}
        public string scannerType {get;set;}
        public string scannerID {get;set;}
        public string siteName {get;set;}
        public string inspDose {get;set;}
        public string expDose {get;set;}
        public string kernel { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I do like this approach, I might implement this